# Why should I input on the second line of the console?

Tags: c++, stream, getline

[image]

Why should I input something on the second line of the console?

```cpp
int main() {
    string s;
    while (true) {
        cout << "Input: ";
        char a = getline(cin, s).get();
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are reading *twice* from `std::cin`.

The [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function returns the stream, and then you call `get` on the stream which requires you to enter something else.

*And* that you apparently only have to input once is because you actually enter *three* characters on the second input: `'f'`, `'d'` and a *newline*. So the first `get` call will read the `'f'`. Then the next iteration the `getline` call will read `"d\n"` and the `get` call will read the next inbput you write and so on.

Simple solution? Don't call `get`:

```
getline(cin, s);
cout << s << '\n';
```